# cannot type registers with shift (specially + and *) on vim

Tags: linux, keyboard, vim

I'm using vim 9.0.1182-1 (the -1 is for arch packages, not sure about patches, reading up on them still), both on kde (both X11 and wayland) and the native TTY.

On all those environments, i cannot type registers name that require a modifier key, such as Shift! I already tested without any customization (removed my `~/.vimrc` and `~/.vim/`)

for example: i can type, in command mode, `"xyy` and yank to the `x` register, etc. Every single register name will work, until I press a modifier key.

For example, when I type `"+yy` what happens is, i see the commands being echoed on the bottom right corner as I press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>'"</kbd> i see `"`, but when i press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>=+</kbd> i get `"+`, then a beep, and then command area is erased, and finally when I continue the command `yy` i get the text into the unamed register instead of the `+` register.

this happens for most key above the number row. I can use the register `"Ayy` just fine, same for `"@` and `"%` and `"_`. but `!@$^&*()+` will cause the issue. I honestly do not care for much of them besides `+` and `*`.

edit: this is all local. no ssh involved. Nor tmux/screen either.

Answer (score 0):

when vim is compiled *without* the `+xterm_clipboard` option, as is the case with the vim package in archlinux, it will Beep and refuse to use registers which require that feature. So you cannot even type the commands `"+`, `"*`, `"~`

solution is to install a version that have that compile option selected, which in most distros will be the `gvim` package.